# How can I free memory for unused elements in 3D vectors?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, multidimensional-array

I generated 100*100*500 vector (or lets say array). I fill in elements randomly. Some elements stay empty. Can I free memory for unused elements. Or, vector data structure does already do it?

Thank you

Comment: No, you can't and no, it doesn't.

Comment: Have you considered a [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) ?

Comment: You may use std::map or std::unordered_map if there are many non-initialized elements. Or, if your elements is heavy objects and you really need vector, you can use lazy initialization for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot free memory that is occupied by a single element inside an array. Arrays are allocated and freed as contiguous memory blocks. You might consider storing your data inside a linked list instead, to accomplish that functionality. If your question is about saving memory, sparse vectors come to my mind.

Edit:
Now that we have clarified (in the comment section) that your aim is to store and graphically represent a given set of 3d data, I can come up with a more detailed answer:

A commonly used way to sparsely store 3d data is an [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree). For use with some kind of voxel-engine, an octree could easily be implemented like this:

```
enum AtomType
{
    NoType,
    SolidType,
    StrangeType
};

class OctreeNode
{
    public:
        virtual OctreeNode* getSubNode(unsigned index) = 0;
        virtual AtomType getContent(void) = 0;
};

class OctreeBranchNode : public OctreeNode
{
    public:
        OctreeNode* getSubNode(unsigned index)
        {
            if (subNodes) return subNodes[index]; else return nullptr;
        }

        AtomType getContent(void) { return NoType; }

    private:
        OctreeNode** subNodes;
};

class OctreeAtomNode : public OctreeNode
{
    public:
        OctreeNode* getSubNode(unsigned index) { return nullptr; }

        AtomType getContent(void) { return content; }

    private:
        AtomType content;
};
```

The point is, that you don't need to store coordinates this way, because the 3d-position of each node is clear from its position inside the tree-hierarchy.

If you want to actually render your data set, you might want to try out [marching cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) or even render every atom as a cubic box (doesn't matter if the data set is large enough and thus atoms are pretty small). There is also a nice [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/letsmakeavoxelengine/) on how to write a voxel engine based on OpenGL.

Comment: yes, indeed, sparse vectors sound good. Could you please recommend me a good resource to study?

Comment: @kemalacikgoz do you want to write your own implementation for education purpose, or would you mind to use a library? Anyway you might want to have a look on [SparseLib](http://math.nist.gov/sparselib++/). Boost also has a [sparseVector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector_sparse.htm) implementation.

Comment: I can use a library Rene R. , thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate...

Comment: @kemalacikgoz in this case I would recommend Boost [uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm), which `vector_sparse.hpp` is part of.

Comment: ok, now I will struggle a little bit to learn sparse matrix manipulation. I mean I'm going to use this 3D vector to store 3D position of boxes (cubes) that form a volume using OpenGL... (I mean, I approximate a 3D structure, for instance a vase by using tousands or millions of boxes.)  Than I may need to rotate, or translate all the elements by OpenGL.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I got you wrong... what you really wanted was not `int arr[100*100*500]` but rather `int arr[100][100][500]`, right? Well, in this case, an [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) data structure might help you. You're going to write some kind of voxel-engine, right?

Comment: I heard these octrees. It divides the space into boxes (not cubic, though) to cover objects with boxes, that might be useful for collision detection...

Comment: Well, octrees have certain advantages when it comes to collision detection or LOD calculation. But primarily they serve as 3-dim sparse data storage. [Ogre3d](http://www.ogre3d.org/) for example uses octrees in its OctreeSceneManager. Judging from your comment, it might be exactly what you need.

Comment: I see, OpenGL implementation is another issue. Actually Rene, I asked a question in OpengGL forum a while ago... It is a shame nobody answered... you can visit this link to see what I actually do!!!
http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182579-How-to-generate-random-burrs-on-a-surface?p=1254308#post1254308

Comment: Yes, I searched for octree, guess what, that's exactly what I need... :-) Thank you very very very much Rene...

Comment: Ok, I got it. FEM is something my brother is actually an expert in. I am only a mathematician but I do know how to visualize 3d data. I will edit my above answer and give you some more detailed information on this, but it may take me a while.

Comment: thank you so much... I wish I could also help you, too! :-) but I'm not an expert in computer science or coding. However, I can help in mechanical engineering if you need. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of elements you save in the array...
You could use a pointer array and set all the elements to nullptr/NULL. So you can create new elements on the heap with the new operator.
But this solutions is senseless if the elements are as small as the pointers itselves.

Comment: I tried to list 2D grids in another vector. I followed a loop to delete entire grid if it is empty. That saved almost 20%. But still requires another computation loop. I do want to do it using basic elements of C++. Actually, my question is as in this link... Please visit this address: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182579-How-to-generate-random-burrs-on-a-surface?p=1254308#post1254308

Comment: I daresay that I would use a upside down treestructure to represent the metal burrs. The root is the end the leaves are at the base structure or in the "air". But this wouldn't be a basic C++ element

Comment: yes, this seems promising, too. Rene gave a quite comprehensive answer. I will first try it. Then after I feel confident, I may try this, too! Nick, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `std::vector`, and "100*100*500" means "vector whose capacity is 5000000" note that `std::vector` container provides fast indexing and direct data access because all data is stored in a single memory block. In c++ you can write something like this:

```
int* arr = new int[5]; 
arr[0] = 1; 
arr[4] = 5;
```

In this example we have an array whose capacity is 5, but 1st, 2nd and 3rd elements are still unused, but there's no way to free memory that was allocated, but still unused. You can also create a new array whose capacity is 2, then copy all elements to the new one, and then delete your initial array. Here's how `std::vector` works. In c++11 you may also use `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()`, but this does not solve your problem, because `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()` does not compacts the array, but just removes unused memory allocation from the back of the vector.

Comment: Thank you Roman Chehowsky, this helped me to understand basics. I will try to use sparse library suggested by Rene R. . Do you think that sparse library can solve my problem?

Comment: @kemalacikgoz I did not see your problem, but I think it will help you. But in my opinion 'boost' is better. Boost is used in many projects, so at the same time you'll gain experience.

Comment: Thank you, all of you... Now, at least I have an idea and a direction to follow...